# How can I restrict user access to a specific database in Redis using ACL

Tags: database, redis, redis-server

I have a user `user1` and I need to restrict `user1` from accessing database 2. How can I achieve this using `ACL`? The user should be able to access any other databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACL isn't designed for that, and I don't recommend using Redis' logical databases for multi-tenancy - just use a different Redis instance for each user.

That said, something like this should work:

```
ACL SETUSER user1 ... -@all +select|1
```

Comment: Can you explain the `-select|2` part?

Comment: Sorry for misleading - I've edited the answer to what *is* supported.

Comment: Note that the ACL above is only applied to the `select` command. The user can still access the database when it is specified as initial database for the connection (e.g. `redis-cli -n 1`). See https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8099 for details.

Comment: The ACL rules provided in the Github issue mentioned seem to work better for me:

`ACL SETUSER user1 on >password +@all ~* -select +select|1`

The ACL rules in the accepted answer seem to only allow for `SELECT 1`, and nothing else.

Comment: `-select` just  stop the user change database when login，but the user still has access to other logic database when login into other database. there is also concern do not use database in the future https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8099#issuecomment-741868975

Answer (score 0):

`-select` only stop switch database when logined.
user still have access to other database.

i think we just should not use `database` any more: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8099